# Error retrieving user's email address from UserPrincipal.current.EmailAddress

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, active-directory

I am using the following to retrieve a user's email address on Windows which works for me and most of our clients, but one client is running into an error for multiple users.

`var email = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;`

The error:
"The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist."

We have verified the correct email is populated in the "mail" attribute on the user's AD object.

I have researched the error and found multiple sources stating this error is likely caused by insufficient active directory permissions, but I have been unable to track down what specifically we need to change.

For testing, I have been using the follow in PowerShell, and the users experiencing the issue get the same error. When I run the commands in PowerShell it returns my email address as expected:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current.EmailAddress
```

A code change is not possible, so I am wondering what, if any changes we could make to active directory settings that would allow this code to run without error?

Comment: When you say you got the "same" results in PowerShell, do you mean you get the error there too?

Comment: Yes, the users who are experiencing the problem get the error with the PowerShell commands, I do not.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily a solution, but additional troubleshooting. Try doing this in PowerShell for one of the affected users:

```
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User
$user = [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$sid>"
$user.RefreshCache("mail")
$user.mail
```

`[ADSI]` is a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators) for [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry), which is what `UserPrincipal` uses behind the scenes. I'm not a fan of using `UserPrincipal` (or anything in the `AccountManagement` namespace) because it hides a lot of the details from you. You have less control of what it's requesting from the server, and thus performance too.

When you create a `UserPrincipal` object, it goes out to AD and loads a bunch of the user's attributes. I suspect that it might not even be the `mail` attribute that it's complaining about. So using this code will narrow that down. It will load *only* the `mail` attribute and nothing else (that's what [`RefreshCache()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache#system-directoryservices-directoryentry-refreshcache(system-string())) does).

Comment: This was helpful in verifying the user's mail attribute was set correctly, but we still do not know which permissions/settings are causing UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress call to fail.

Comment: The quickest way to figure it out is to debug the .NET source code, which can be done in .NET Core now. If you're able to create a simple .NET Core project that replicates the issue, and debug in Visual Studio following [the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644394/1202807), you can stop at the exception within the .NET source and examine the local variables and figure out which attribute it's complaining about (hopefully).